# How to write the proper syntax for this line of code in my SQL dynamic Pivot Query?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, syntax, pivot

I have a dynamic pivot query running on SQL Server 2014. This is my original query and it runs fine:

```
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cols VARCHAR(max)

 SET @cols = (SELECT DISTINCT a.FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE + ','
              FROM   P5FOLIOCHARGE a
                    LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER b
                           ON a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
             WHERE  b.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER = '39576189-1'
             AND FOC_NETAMOUNT NOT LIKE '-%'
             FOR xml path(''))

 SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

 SET @sql = 'SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT b.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER,
                   a.FOC_ACCOUNT,
                   a.FOC_PROPERTY,
                   a.FOC_DATE,
                   a.FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE,
                       CASE WHEN a.FOC_NETAMOUNT > 0 THEN a.FOC_NETAMOUNT   ELSE 0 END AS FOC_NETAMOUNT
                FROM P5FOLIOCHARGE a
                     LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER b ON a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
                where b.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER = ''39576189-1'' 
                AND FOC_NETAMOUNT NOT LIKE ''-%'')a
                PIVOT (Sum(FOC_NETAMOUNT)
                 FOR FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE IN (' + @cols + ')) pv '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

I have now modified it a bit but I am running into a syntax error with the following line of code that I have added:

```
WHERE  datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) = 'FEBRUARY 2015'
```

The query now looks as this:

```
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cols VARCHAR(max)

SET @cols = (SELECT DISTINCT a.FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE + ','
         FROM   P5FOLIOCHARGE a
                LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER b
                       ON a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
         WHERE  datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) = 'FEBRUARY 2015'
         AND FOC_PROPERTY = 'ZIL'
         AND FOC_NETAMOUNT NOT LIKE '-%'
         FOR xml path(''))

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

SET @sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT b.FOH_PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER,
                   a.FOC_ACCOUNT,
                   a.FOC_date,
                   a.FOC_PROPERTY,
                   a.FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE,
                   CASE WHEN a.FOC_NETAMOUNT > 0 THEN a.FOC_NETAMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS FOC_NETAMOUNT
            FROM P5FOLIOCHARGE a
                 LEFT JOIN P5FOLIOHEADER b ON a.FOC_ACCOUNT = b.FOH_ACCOUNT
            WHERE  datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) = ''FEBRUARY 2015''
            AND FOC_PROPERTY = 'ZIL'  
            AND FOC_NETAMOUNT NOT LIKE ''-%'')a
           PIVOT (Sum(FOC_NETAMOUNT)
                 FOR FOC_TRANSACTIONCODE IN (' + @cols + ')) pv '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

I am having a syntax error (on the code I mentioned above) where it appears the second time in the query (that is, after the SET @ sql=....)

I have tried several combinations of using the ' sign but it still fails. I guess it must be a simple coding syntax error but it just isn't working for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Not sure but please check this

1. `WHERE  datename(m,FOC_DATE) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) = ''FEBRUARY 2015''`  it should be `WHERE  datename(m,FOC_DATE) + '' '' + cast(datepart(yyyy,FOC_DATE) as varchar) = ''FEBRUARY 2015''`
2. `AND FOC_PROPERTY = 'ZIL'` it should be `AND FOC_PROPERTY = ''ZIL''`